# MySQL TIMESTAMP stoped working on summer time transition

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures, timezone, timestamp

I have a stored procedure that was crashing yesterday. It begins like this:

```
DECLARE v_today TIMESTAMP;
SET v_today = (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
```

I've fixed it changing the type of `v_today` to `DATETIME`. But I want to understand why it was generating an error only yesterday (when Brazil started summer time).

The error was:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2017-10-15 00:00:00' for column 'v_today' at row 1:
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error did it generate? Does `SET v_today = CURDATE();` work correctly?  Please [edit] your question to give more details.

Comment: I bet this is a bug in MySQL. Here's the time transition discipline for Brazil. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia  It looks like the TIMESTAMP value  `2017-10-15 00:00:00` doesn't exist, and needs to be pushed forward an hour to  `2017-10-15 01:00:00`. But MySQL just gacks.

Comment: It makes sense! I believe that's why... So `TIMESTAMP` does not accept the time `2017-10-15 00:00:00`, because it doesn't exists in real live. Thank you @O.Jones .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is a bug in MySQL. Here's the time transition discipline for Brazil. timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia It looks like the TIMESTAMP value `2017-10-15 00:00:00` doesn't exist, and needs to be pushed forward an hour to `2017-10-15 01:00:00`. But MySQL just gacks.